# What is happening with SuccessCount in 1.11?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am working on my map and I really want to know WHY the `SuccessCount` tag doesn't work anymore in 1.11?
I got at this conclusion when I tried to test if there are 2 players in a certain area. I read all the commands again in again, place and replaced back the command blocks (the command blocks can bug sometimes) and even brought a second account in that area to be sure.

[image]

**1** - `execute @e[type=armor_stand,name=lobby] ~ ~ ~ testfor @a[r=10,c=2]`

**2** - `/testforblock ~1 ~ ~ minecraft:repeating_command_block -1 {SuccessCount:2}`

**3** - `say test`

Can someone help me with this? I tried so many solutions, but it kinda gets tidious to do anymore. I would like an explanation or maybe other solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working correctly; you are receiving the success count from the `/execute` command, not the `/testfor` command. If there is only 1 armor stand running the `/testfor` command, then the success count is going to be 1 if that `/testfor` command succeeds (causing `/execute` to succeed the 1 time).

You will need to rely on other methods to track total, such as removing `/execute` and using hard-coded coordinates:

```
/testfor @a[x=10,y=64,z=10,r=10,c=2]
```

Or scores to track the number of players (and detect that score instead of the `SuccessCount` value):

```
/scoreboard players set #NearLobby OBJ 0
/execute @e[type=armor_stand,name=lobby] ~ ~ ~ /execute @a[r=10,c=2] ~ ~ ~ /scoreboard players add #NearLobby OBJ 1
/scoreboard players test #NearLobby OBJ 2 *
```

Comment: Thank you! I know this solution is a little pain for my future commands, but it's worth it

Answer (score 1):

`/testfor`'s SuccessCount is how many entities are found, **however** `/execute`'s SuccessCount is how many times the contained command is successfully run.

As your command block contains `/execute`, the SuccessCount is tracking how many times the contained command (`/testfor`) is being successfully run. As `/testfor` is only being run once (I assume there's only one "lobby" stand), it can only ever succeed once.

---

As a simple workaround without having to go into stats or scoreboards, you could reverse the first command:

```
execute @a ~ ~ ~ testfor @e[type=armor_stand,name=lobby,r=10]
```

This means that the `/testfor` command will run multiple times and succeed once for every player near the stand.

Though note that this would no longer be capped at 2.

---

Alternatively, you can use command stats:

```
/stats entity @e[type=armor_stand,name=lobby] set SuccessCount @e[type=armor_stand,name=lobby,c=1] PlayersFound
```

Beforehand, you'll need to add a `PlayersFound` dummy objective, and also initiate the lobby armor stand's score to something (e.g: `/scoreboard players set @e[type=armor_stand,name=lobby] PlayersFound 0`) before stats will work.

Then, after running the first command, you can check if the armor stand found at least 2 players with `@e[type=armor_stand,name=lobby,score_PlayersFound_min=2]`.

With this, you're checking the result of the `/testfor` command that the armor stand is running, rather than the `/execute` command that the command block is running.

Comment: Your solution is good, but Skylinerw's one is briefly explained :)